# Common component across routes with different content

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a component called `Header` which exists across all routes, while the rest of the app changes. So to accomplish this, my main render code looks about like this (using ES6):

```
render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <Header></Header>
      <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/details/:id" component={Details} />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The challenge is that the contents of the `<Header>` should vary slightly depending on the route, for example a unique title per route.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case for flux. You have route handlers that create an action when they mount. This action goes into the HeaderStore. The Header component listens to the Header store and renders based on it.

You can see an example of this here:

- [CurrentBoardStore](https://github.com/bleeding-edge-react-sample-app/bleeding-edge-react-sample-app.github.io/blob/master/src/stores/CurrentBoardStore.js) holds the current page info
- [BoardPage](https://github.com/bleeding-edge-react-sample-app/bleeding-edge-react-sample-app.github.io/blob/master/src/pages/BoardPage/BoardPage.js#L17) updates the store when it mounts/updates
- [SubBoardHeaderWrapper](https://github.com/bleeding-edge-react-sample-app/bleeding-edge-react-sample-app.github.io/blob/master/src/organisms/SubBoardHeaderWrapper.js) renders the header with data from CurrentBoardStore

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently using Flux but wasn't sure how the current route would fit into it. So it's essentially maintaining state separate from the routing, I think I like that. One question, you say "route handlers", is this the same as the component in `<Route component={MyView} />`?

Comment: Yeah they were formerly called route handlers. Not sure what to call them now.

Comment: Accepting this answer. All the solutions work, but I think ultimately relying on Flux store's is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all the great answers! Still mulling them over.

To throw another solution into the mix, I found that I can actually put arbitrary properties on the `Route`, so I added `title`:

```
<Route title="My Title" component={App} />
```

And I re-shuffled around my route hierarchy to include the header in `Router` (in the top-level `Route` component instead of outside any route as before), so my main render code looks like this:

```
<Router>
  <Route component={App}>
    <Route path="/" component={Home} title="Home" />
    <Route path="/detail/:id" component={Detail} title="Details" />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

And my `App` contains the header and is passed the current route's title:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    var route = this.props.routes[this.props.routes.length - 1];
    return (
      <div>
        <Header title={route.title} />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

But I can't say this is the best solution. I do like that I can just put `title` on each route now, but I worry about the coupling and the way I have to extract the properties from the `routes` array.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it (I'm pretty sure there is a better way, but this might help you out) looks like the following:

**index.js**

```
// define routes
const routes = (
  <Route component={App} path="/">
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/details/:id" component={Details} />
  </Route>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Router>{routes}</Router>, document.getElementById('your_id'));
```

**App.js**

```
render() {
    return (
       <div>
        <Header routerProps={this.props.children} />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**Header.js**

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // Get access to the pathname, it contains a string like "/details/"
    console.log(nextProps.routerProps.props.location.pathname);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me understand how to structure my routes better. I've moved the header into the top-level `App` route and render `props.children` like you've shown here. Instead of passing the router children to the header, though, I found that I can actually declare properties right on the route (like `title`) and pass them in... is that a bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

instead of putting header there.. put the header in a layout component. each view should use the layout component and you can pass whatever you want the header to be.

```
export class Layout extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return <div>
            <Header title={this.props.title} />
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    }
}
```

all of your views can use this same component like so

```
export class SomeComponent extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return <Layout title="Some Component Title">
            <div>my elements here</div>
        </Layout>
    }
}
```

NOTE: the beauty of using something like this, is you can set up any other default messaging like for instance lets say you want to have a flash message appear... someone clicks on something and you want a message to say 'You've successfully registered!' (in this example). You can include your flash messaging in the layout and simply dispatch an event to show the message. This can be done with modals too and really whatever your app requirements are :)

Comment: Thanks this a good idea. I'm not sure I followed what you meant by the "flash message". Initially I didn't like the idea that breaking the hierarchy in this way, since now each page contains a duplicate layout, as opposed to a single layout containing different content... but I guess React's diffing on updates makes that difference pretty insignificant.

Comment: @aaron if you go to linkedin and update your profile you will see one of those flash messages.. It's basically just a message that pops up to tell the user something, and then it goes away after a short amount of time... The reason why each page of your app should use the layout is for a lot of reasons, not only can you have this functionality but it also makes each of your pages follow the same pattern and are set up the same way which makes it easier on you when you need to go change something :)