# How to nest a common react-redux component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have developed a common react-redux component called TimerDialog and will embed it into an existing react application. The existing app's configuration is as below:

```
const app = (
    <div>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <IntlProvider>
                <Router history={history}>
                    <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                </Router>
            </IntlProvider>
        </Provider>
    </div>
);
const target = document.getElementById('app');
render(app, target);
```

My common component TimerDialog has been built into the existing app as a node_module. I am planning to add it simply inside the Provider as it also use store.

```
<Provider store={store}>
            <IntlProvider>
                <Router history={history}>
                    <TimerDialog />   <------- The common component
                    <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                </Router>
            </IntlProvider>
        </Provider>
```

However, such configuration doesn't take any effect. I don't want to code the TimerDialog in any existing component because it is designed as a shared one. 
Is there a way to configure it commonly in the application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Common component across routes with different content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645465/common-component-across-routes-with-different-content)

Comment: I don't quite understand what your issue is? Can you share some more code? Maybe share the <TimerDialog /> code, or the line where you import it.