# Reactsjs Hide button on certain paths

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, components, show-hide

I have a header

```
const Header = () => (
  <header className="header">
    <h1 className="title">Sport shop</h1>
    <a href="/add" className="addBtn">Add a new shirt</a>
    <a href="/add" className="addBtn">back to homepage</a>
  </header>
);
```

This is a common component but once I am on the route '/addshirt' I only want to show the back button. Similarly when I am in the homepage I only want to show the 'add a new shirt button'

I am suing react router

```
  <Router>
        <div className="inner">
          <Header />
          <Route exact path="/" component={home} />
          <Route exact path="/addShirt" component={AddShirt} />
        </div>
      </Router>
```

Comment: Duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645465/common-component-across-routes-with-different-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same `<Route />` component for this! It renders the passed `component` or `render` function only if the `<Route />` matches the given path.

Try something like

```
const Header = () => (   
  <header className="header">
    <h1 className="title">Sport shop</h1>
    <Route exact path="/" render={() => <a href="/add" className="addBtn">Add a new shirt</a>} />
    <Route exact path="/addShirt" render={() => <a href="/add" className="addBtn">back to homepage</a>} />   
  </header> 
);
```

Also check out [the docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route) for the Route component.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. The router api is pretty extensive, need to get a good look at it.